# horizontal paging using viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview, horizontal-scrolling

i need to achieve horizontal scrolling of pages while swiping

i have loaded data in the order of json ,inside the textview and webview

i have used viewpager for achieving that operation

im receiving the error as shown in log cat

i have used removeView() method ,error is showing up again

Kindly Help me to solve this

Thanks in advance

**My Code**

```
package singlearticle;


import com.yslabs.yourstory.R;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class SingleArticle extends Activity {

    String t = single.title;
    String p = single.permalink;
    String f = single.featured_img;
    String a = single.author;
    String d = single.date;
    String articleComment = "article url" + p;
    private WebView web1, fbCommentview;
    ConnectionDetector checkConnection;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ViewPager viewPage;
    MyPagerAdapter mypageAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint({ "InflateParams", "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "HandlerLeak",
            "NewApi" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singlearticle);
        viewPage = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
        mypageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        viewPage.setAdapter(mypageAdapter);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8")));
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(SingleArticle.this);
        View mCustomView = mInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.customactionbar,null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        Typeface fontt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "helvetica.ttf");
        mTitleTextView.setTypeface(fontt);
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.backicon);
        // getActionBar().setIcon(
        // new
        // ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleArticle.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        final Handler h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
        h.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 500);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, t + "\n" + p);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);

            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            web1.loadUrl("");
            web1.stopLoading();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient

    {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous
    // screen.

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)

    {

        if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            web1.loadUrl("");
            web1.stopLoading();

            finish();

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        int articleCount = 5;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // returns article count
            return articleCount;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            // assigns object to view

            return view == ((LinearLayout)obj);
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            d = d.substring(0, d.length() - 3);

            String c = single.content;
            c = c.replace("src=\"//", "src=\"https://");
            final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
            String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(c, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
            String htmldata = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><style = text/css> img{width:100%!important;height:auto!important;} iframe{width:100sp;max-height:100sp;}a { color:#3366CC; text-decoration: none; } </style> <body style = 'line-height:25px;'>"
                    + c + "</body></html>";
            TextView titleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singletitle);
            titleTxt.setText(t);
            // tt = titleTxt.getText().toString();
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "Helvetica Neue UltraLight.ttf");
            Typeface font22 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "helvetica-neue-regular-1361522098.ttf");
            titleTxt.setTypeface(font);
            titleTxt.setTypeface(font22);
            titleTxt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            TextView authorTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleauthor);
            authorTxt.setText(a);
            Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "helvetica.ttf");
            authorTxt.setTypeface(font1);
            TextView dateTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singledate);
            dateTxt.setText(d);
            Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "helvetica.ttf");
            dateTxt.setTypeface(font2);
            TextView permalinkTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleperlink);
            permalinkTxt.setText(p);
            permalinkTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // pp = permalinkTxt.getText().toString();
            // datep.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
            web1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // web1.setInitialScale(65);
            web1.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(18);
            web1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            web1.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
            // web1.loadUrl("http://dev.skyle.co/fbSDK.php?data="+urlEncoded);
            web1.loadData(htmldata, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);

            web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    Intent in = new Intent(SingleArticle.this, webview.class);
                    webclass.webdata = url.toString();
                    startActivity(in);
                    return true;
                }

            });

            fbCommentview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fbCommentview);
            /*
             * to check internet and show/hide facebook part
             */
            checkConnection = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            isInternetPresent = checkConnection.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Internet Working",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fbCommentview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Internet Not Working",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fbCommentview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            fbCommentview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            fbCommentview.getSettings()
                    .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            fbCommentview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            fbCommentview.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(18);
            fbCommentview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            fbCommentview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
            fbCommentview.loadUrl(articleComment);

            System.out.println("Title" + t);
            System.out.println("Content" +c);
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(SingleArticle.this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            layout.addView(titleTxt);
            layout.addView(dateTxt);
            layout.addView(web1);
            layout.addView(fbCommentview);
            container.addView(layout);
            return layout;

        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }

    }

}
```

**The Error in LOGCAT**
[image: error in logcat]

Comment: A view can only have a single parent. The view that you are adding is already part of another view hierarchy. If you really want to reuse it then you have to remove it from its parent in its existing view hierarchy. here  container.addView(layout);

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy thank u ,i have a doubt should i need to remove this container.addView(layout);

Comment: @sonam A view can have only one parent, so you must need to remove its parent before reusing it, I dont think so you need to remove container.addView(layout).

Comment: @pratt thanks ,im unaware about to remove the parent and also im a newbie to android  could u help me to solve this

Comment: TextView titleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singletitle) how your getting these views by using this code ?

Comment: @sonam do one thing, just create one xml (layout) file first, which you want to show. Then I will tell you what you need to do is okay?

Comment: @pratt im showing in 3 widgets one textview and 2 webview

Comment: @sonam so if you can not do anything, then we need to continue here only dear.

Comment: @pratt, sorry for late reply, can you please help me to solve this problem and i have complete this task in 1 hrs please......

Comment: @sonam have you created xml file with textview and webviews?

Comment: @pratt yes i have like that

Comment: @sonam ok can you please tell me the name of that xml?

Comment: @pratt singlearticle.xml

Comment: @sonam that is the main xml, you have to create for viewpager content, seprate xml.

Comment: @pratt ok ill create separate  xml can u tell me how to add it in this

Comment: @sonam posting answer for the same.

Comment: @pratt Ok Thanks Wait I'm implementing

Answer (score 0):

here

```
TextView titleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singletitle);
TextView authorTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleauthor);
TextView permalinkTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleperlink);
web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
fbCommentview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fbCommentview);
```

these all the views contains one parent already.. because of that reason your unable to add it again..if you want to add to the layout here. you have to create those textview like this, instead of getting from xml.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
```

and then add to the layout.

Comment: thanks ,now the error is gone but instead of content is its showing only textview

Comment: See create all the views and and add to one Linearlayout and then add that Linearlayout to the container.

Comment: i cannot get the view of article

Answer (score 0):

Replace below method and try:

```
    @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater;
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlearticle, container, false);
            d = d.substring(0, d.length() - 3);

            String c = single.content;
            c = c.replace("src=\"//", "src=\"https://");
            final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
            String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(c, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
            String htmldata = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><style = text/css> img{width:100%!important;height:auto!important;} iframe{width:100sp;max-height:100sp;}a { color:#3366CC; text-decoration: none; } </style> <body style = 'line-height:25px;'>"
                    + c + "</body></html>";
            TextView titleTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singletitle);
            titleTxt.setText(t);
            // tt = titleTxt.getText().toString();
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "Helvetica Neue UltraLight.ttf");
            Typeface font22 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "helvetica-neue-regular-1361522098.ttf");
            titleTxt.setTypeface(font);
            titleTxt.setTypeface(font22);
            titleTxt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            TextView authorTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singleauthor);
            authorTxt.setText(a);
            Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "helvetica.ttf");
            authorTxt.setTypeface(font1);
            TextView dateTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singledate);
            dateTxt.setText(d);
            Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "helvetica.ttf");
            dateTxt.setTypeface(font2);
            TextView permalinkTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singleperlink);
            permalinkTxt.setText(p);
            permalinkTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // pp = permalinkTxt.getText().toString();
            // datep.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            web1 = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
            web1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // web1.setInitialScale(65);
            web1.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(18);
            web1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            web1.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
            // web1.loadUrl("http://dev.skyle.co/fbSDK.php?data="+urlEncoded);
            web1.loadData(htmldata, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);

            web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    Intent in = new Intent(SingleArticle.this, webview.class);
                    webclass.webdata = url.toString();
                    startActivity(in);
                    return true;
                }

            });

            fbCommentview = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.fbCommentview);
            /*
             * to check internet and show/hide facebook part
             */
            checkConnection = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            isInternetPresent = checkConnection.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Internet Working",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fbCommentview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Internet Not Working",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fbCommentview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            fbCommentview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            fbCommentview.getSettings()
                    .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            fbCommentview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            fbCommentview.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(18);
            fbCommentview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            fbCommentview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
            fbCommentview.loadUrl(articleComment);

//            System.out.println("Title" + t);
//            System.out.println("Content" +c);
//            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(SingleArticle.this);
//            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
//            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
//                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
//            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
//            layout.addView(titleTxt);
//            layout.addView(dateTxt);
//            layout.addView(web1);
//            layout.addView(fbCommentview);
//            container.addView(layout);
            return view;

        }
```

Comment: im getting null pointer expection at  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlearticle, container, false);